# Firebase audiences - what is signed in with user id

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

I believe that "User ID" maps to the value I set in my client `firebaseAnalytics.setUserId(userId)`

but what is "Signed in with user ID"?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signed in with ID is from the `User-ID` feature and is typically used for cross-platform identification, these are generated through the Firebase Auth through validation of the user.

You can read about it here:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9213390?hl=en&ref_topic=9303474

and importantly any caveats if you wish to utilize it here:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9835194?hl=en&ref_topic=9303474